# LED with an onboard circuit

Tags: led, timer

A friend of mine purchased a pack of little ball shaped widgets from Banggood. Each contains an RGBA LED with a integrated timing circuit inside the LED lens itself. The ball flashes in different colors, and different patterns in sequence.

[image]

When opening one of the widgets, it simply contains an RGBA LED, which has only two leads for connecting the battery.

Does anyone know where one can purchase one of these LEDs or possibly know of the whereabouts for a datasheet for this product?

Comment: have you tried google?

Comment: Literally the first result when I typed "Colour changing LED" into google - [Product](https://www.kitronik.co.uk/3527-colour-changing-5mm-diffused-led-750mcd.html) and [Datasheet](https://www.kitronik.co.uk/pdf/3527-colour-changing-5mm-diffused-led-750mcd.pdf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These smart flashing RGB LEDS have an inbuilt IC which blinks/toggles the 3 separate RGB LEDs located inside.
All one need to do is to provide a DC supply, the IC will randomly switches the colour.

Checkout this one,
https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11450

In datasheet you can see the application diagram showing IC & three individual R,G & B LEDs.